# Postgresql: Values of multiple rows in one row

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have the following database:

Car: {[CarID, HorsePower, Brand, HeadDesigner]}

DesignsCar:{[CarID, DesID]}

Designer:{[DesID, Name]}

You should note that while every Car has only 1 HeadDesigner, multiple people can design cars (as in work on them).

Say I have 10 cars in my database. For CarID (1..9) only one DesID per CarID in DesignsCar. 
However, for carID 10 we have 3 people working on it (carID has 3 entries in DesignsCar because 3 people worked on it).

Say I do this:

```
select *
from car c 
left outer join designscar ds on c.carid = ds.carid 
left outer join designer d on frb.persnr = r.persnr
```

This gives me 12 rows, when I only want 10. The reason why this gives me 12 rows should be clear: for carID 10 we have 3 people working on it (carID has 3 entries in DesignsCar because 3 people worked on it).

I hope I've done a good job explaining this problem, **so here comes my question:**

How do I modify the query above so I get 10 Rows. For CarID 10 I'd like the 3 designers to be written in one column (like, comma separated but anything works as long it's in one column).

Is that possible?

Comment: Edit your question and show the results you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to aggregate the values.  Here is one possibility:

```
select c.*, 
       array_agg(d.name) as designer_names
from car c left outer join
     designscar ds
     on c.carid = ds.carid left outer join
     designer d
     on frb.persnr = r.persnr
group by c.carid ;   -- allowed assuming `carid` is the primary key
```

Comment: This is what I was looking for. Will mark as answer asap